# How to use unless (or when) in an Esqueleto query?

Tags: sql, haskell, esqueleto

I build a query that joins a few tables and restricts the result further *unless* one field called `IncludeAll` equals `True`.

I'm trying to write it like this

```
fetch i = runDb . select . from $ \(a, b, c) -> do
  where_ $
        a ^. AId ==. valkey i
    &&. b ^. BField1 ==. a ^. AField2
    &&. c ^. CField1 ==. a ^. AField3
  unless (unValue $ b ^. BIncludeAll) $
    where_ $ b ^. BField2 == c ^. CField2
  return  b
```

But I get the following error

> Couldn't match expected type `Bool` with actual type `Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Language.Value Bool` in the first argument of `unless`

So the `unValue` somehow does not do the trick. Indeed, something like `b ^. BIncludeAll` has the type `expr (Value a)`.

Looking at the [definition of `SqlExpr`](https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/blob/d153dbd40a090f927da2917d6afd50c26c37e84d/src/Database/Esqueleto/Internal/Sql.hs) in the source didn't help me, either:

It's an ADT:

```
 data SqlExpr a where ...
```

PS: I use an SQL backend, but ideally that should not matter, right?

Comment: Isn't that just `... &&. (b ^. BIncludeAll ||. b ^. BField2 ==. c ^. CField2)`?

Comment: It seems unlikely to me this would work, because `unless` is a Haskell side thing and you'd need it to be something that's happening in the backend.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `when_ … then_` in Esqueleto?

Comment: thanks @melpomene, that's what I need. Sometimes these queries still puzzle me. (apart from this nice solution in this case, I don't see why the usage of `unless` should be a bad idea in esqueleto queries; if someone's willing to enlighten me ...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unless`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless) expects a `Bool` as its argument, that means a boolean in the "Haskell world". You are passing it `unValue $ b ^. BIncludeAll`, but `b ^. BIncludeAll` is not of type `Value Bool`, it's an `SqlExpr (Value Bool)`, which represents a boolean expression in the "database world". It's an SQL statement that, when evaluated, returns a boolean. The only way to turn `SqlExpr (Value Bool)` into an actual `Value Bool` is by calling `select $ from $ ...`.

As others have noted, the correct way to do this is to just use `where_ (b ^. BIncludeAll ||. b ^. BField2 ==. c ^. CField2)`.